# Tail bound on difference of shifted binomials (generalization)

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

I have a post [Tail bound on difference of shifted binomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545414/tail-bound-on-difference-of-shifted-binomials) answered before and now I want to consider I slightly generalization of it which can't be solved using the methods in the previous thread.

I want to derive an upper bound on $\mathsf{Pr}\{\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{X_i}{L}-\frac{1}{2})^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{Y_i}{L}-\frac{1}{2})^2\}$ where $X_i,Y_i$ are all independent and $X_i\sim$ Bin($L,p$) where $p\neq \frac{1}{2}$, and $Y_i\sim$ Bin($L,\frac{1}{2}$).

Intuitively, the probability should be vanishing with both $n$ and $L$.

If I use my original method stated [in the pervious post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545414/tail-bound-on-difference-of-shifted-binomials) (which is Chernoff bound combined with Hoeffding's Lemma), I can only get the upper bound 
$\exp\{-16n(\frac{L-1}{L})^2(p^2+\frac{1}{4})^2\}$ which is vanishing with $n$ but not with $L$.

If I use the method by Gabriel Romon [in the pervious post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545414/tail-bound-on-difference-of-shifted-binomials), the upper bound would become $4n\exp\{-\frac{L}{2}(p-\frac{1}{2})^2\}$ which is vanishing with $L$ but not with $n$. (Since we use the union bound.)

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How about taking the minimum of the two upper bounds ?

Comment: Actually $L$ might depends on $n$, taking the minimum makes the second bound intractable. I still think there might be an improvement on the first bound where we can replace the subgaussian term by something like $\exp\{\frac{t^2}{L^2}\}$ which meets our need.